# How to get the Contact Numbers based on the Part of Contact Name in Android?

Tags: android, contacts

I want to get the Contact Numbers based on the Search word.

I tried using the following, but it gives Unknown URL exception.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, partOfContactName.toString());
    Cursor cursorContact =  getApplicationContext().
                              getContentResolver().query(uri, 
                              new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}, null, null, null);
```

By using the above code base I am getting the following exception.

```
01-03 11:11:38.225: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(711): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.android.contacts/contacts/filter/
```

So is there any way to get this done ?

This application is for the devices having Android 2.1+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this by replacing your uri line.: `Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, partOfContactName.toString());`